# Xamarin.Android support with GithubActions workflows? (or how to install JDK programmatically)

Tags: java, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, github-actions

I'm trying to build a Xamarin.Android library with a WindowsVM spawned by a GithubActions workflow (marked as `windows-latest`), and I'm getting this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(798,2):
>   error XA5300: The Java SDK Directory could not be found. Please set
>   via /p:JavaSdkDirectory.

How to install the VisualStudio Xamarin tooling into this VM programmatically before I call the build script? I'm afraid that just installing the Java SDK (as instructed by the error) might not really cut it.

(I'm migrating from AzureDevOps to GithubActions; and this worked out of the box with the former, without the need to specify anything on the buildagent configuration.)

Comment: GitHub Actions is still in Beta, I'm not quite sure it is supposed to work out of the box, with every kind of project Azure Devops supports yet

Comment: Might be irrelevant, but why did you move to Github Actions already ? Seems a bit early

Comment: it's fine if it doesn't work out of the box, I'm not requesting that; I'm just wondering how to install the Xamarin tooling manually via the command line

Comment: I haven't figured out how to do it with a Windows VM, but I figured out how to use a MacOS runner using GitHub Actions. I created a video too that you can see here bit.ly/30crWpc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin.Android 10.x from Visual Studio 2019 16.3 has a fix for this issue, unfortunately you'll need to download and install it during your build--it just came out!

I have been able to build Xamarin.Android projects on Github Actions when using `boots`, as in this example: https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/boots#github-actions